# Handlebars templates, access context variables with a string key

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

Let's say I have a handlebars template like this:

```
      <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
       <div class="entry">
          <h1>{{i18n.title}}</h1>
       </div>
      </script>
```

What I really would like to do is something like this:

```
var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {"title.t":"My New Post"}
console.log(template(context));
```

When I try to parse in a context like above with a string as the key, hanslebars acts like the key is not available. I do understand that normaly the structure should be like this:

```
var context = {
    i18n:{
      title:'test'
    }
}
```

But because I'll get my 118n strings from an external source, it would be easier to just use them as keys. 
Ah and yes, I know projects like i18n.js, but the actual question is: Can I use a string-key in the context object with dots in it and if yes, how can I access them from the handlebars template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot use keys with dots in them. This is because they are part of the syntax. If you could use dots then how would you access children of that element? Instead of dots, use underscore or dash. It's a standard people respect because it doesn't introduce bugs and other weird behaviour.

Comment: So you say it's best to bring in a little Handlebars Helper that replaces . with _?

Comment: No. Do not create a helper to do that because the key will be interpreted by having the `.` in it. If you pass it a string, you'll manage to get it replaced, but you'll have trouble using the helper. I say to have your keys already without `.` in them from where you receive them.

Comment: thats the worst solution I can come up with, but if this is the only one... I guess I have to do a bit more reseach. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I still want to post what I've found out.

If the key to your key:value pair is represented as a string, you could place the string itself in your handlebars template placeholder.

So if your context is:

```
var context = {
    "key":"value"
}
```

As opposed to this:

```
var context = {
    key: "value"
}
```

You could do this in your template to show the value:

```
<p>{{"key"}}</p>
```

So, handlebars will treat it as a property name, and display the value.

Example:

```
var names = {
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Doe"
}
<script id="names-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<p>First Name: {{"first"}}</p>
</script>
```

Will output:

First Name: John

This respects spaces and other characters in your key strings, we tested it, and it works with dots within your strings too. Give it a try and let me know.